# VS Code: How to move cursor automatically from editor to terminal when i hit run in VS Code?

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

I don't want any shortcuts, I tried "code runner" extension but its launches in the OUTPUT section and the cursor starts at the beginning of the text and I can't type anything:
[image: image of terminal]